# Is it possible to use chunked transfer-encoding on a .NET MVC page that uses a master page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, chunked-encoding, transfer-encoding

I have a working example of using chunked transfer-encoding for just .NET, but can't get it to work for an MVC page.

I can't find any implicit support for doing chunked transfer-encoding on an MVC page. Since I can't find any support for doing a chunked transfer-encoding response, I've tried creating my own chunks by writing the chunk length and then the chunk content directly to the HttpResponseBase response object.

I've run into several problems trying to

- put the headers in a separate partial view and sending it as one chunk and then
- rendering the rest of a MVC page that uses a master page as a separate chunk

When I try to write directly to the response object; I'm running into problems rendering a full page(with master page) to a string so that I can get a chunk length. I'm also unsure what to put into the ViewResult that would be returned from the action method.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `this.Response.BufferOutput = false;` in your action method before returning the ViewResult. Then the HttpResponse object should set `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and chunk the response data, rather than buffering it and setting Content-Length.